# Citrus test suite

Tags: integration-testing, test-suite, citrus-framework

I am using Citrus `TestNGCitrusTestDesigner`, I have a few classes annotated with `@Test`. Each class have a few methods. Each method annotated `@Test` and `@CitrusTest`. When I am configuring tests that should be executed during `mvn clean package integration-test` - I am changing `@Test(enabled=true)` to `true` or `false`. How can I do this more effectively? I found this doc: http://www.citrusframework.org/reference/1.0/html/testsuite.html#testsuite-tasks but it is for an old version. Doesn't work in Citrus Framework 2.X.

Answer (score 0):

Citrus runs with TestNG or JUnit framework. This means that you can reuse the mechanisms of these frameworks in order to group tests or define a test suite.

With TestNG for instance you can use different groups of tests or create a testng.xml file that defines the tests to execute in a suite (http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#testng-xml).

With TestNG or JUnit integration in build tools like Maven or Gradle the tests are executable from command line or Java IDE.